# Consumo da api e flatlist

Tags: react-native

Estou tentando consumir a api e mostrar os dados em um card flat list, entretanto ele da o erro 401.

```js
async function ListarConsulta(){
        try {
            // Recuperação do token de acesso
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        
            // Verificação se o token foi corretamente obtido
            if (token) {
                // Fazendo a chamada da API para consultas
                await api.get('/Consultas', {
                    headers: {
                        // Adicionando o token ao cabeçalho de autorização
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                }).then(response => {
                    setListaConsulta(response.data);
                    console.log(response.data);
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(`Deu erro: ${error}`);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('Token de autorização não encontrado');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.